# Writing comments to files with ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

How can one write comments to a given file within sections?

If I have:

```
import ConfigParser
with open('./config.ini', 'w') as f:
    conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    conf.set('DEFAULT', 'test', 1)
    conf.write(f)
```

I will get the file:

```
[DEFAULT]
test = 1
```

But how can I get a file with comments inside `[DEFAULT]` section, like:

```
[DEFAULT]
; test comment
test = 1
```

I know I can write codes to files by doing:

```
import ConfigParser
with open('./config.ini', 'w') as f:
    conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    conf.set('DEFAULT', 'test', 1)
    conf.write(f)
    f.write('; test comment') # but this gets printed after the section key-value pairs
```

Is this a possibility with ConfigParser? And I don't want to try another module because I need to keep my program as "stock" as possible.

Comment: After considering ConfigParser for writing configuration files, I decided to write my file using old standard file interface `f = open('test.ini', 'w'); f.write('blabla')` because the ConfigParser module doesn't even write in a predifined order (because it's using dictionaries, even though one of the examples states that the writing is made in some sort of order: [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#examples))

Comment: If you are still around I'll suggest you write a short answer regarding this and mark it as accepted. I read the proposed answer even after this comment and came to the same conclusion... but took me a while and I have even voted up your selected solution...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the allow_no_value option if you have Version >=  2.7

This snippet:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.add_section('default_settings')
config.set('default_settings', '; comment here')
config.set('default_settings', 'test', 1)
with open('config.ini', 'w') as fp:
    config.write(fp)


config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read('config.ini')
print config.items('default_settings')
```

will create an ini file like this:

```
[default_settings]
; comment here
test = 1
```

Comment: As a side note, this works as long as you're not trying to write comments in the 'DEFAULT' section - there's a check in the write function to avoid writing " = None", but only when not writing out the 'DEFAULT' section.

Comment: Good point. Fortunately, in Python 3.6, the `configparser` module does not have this strange behavior. Thus, `config = configparser.ConfigParser({"; comment": None}, allow_no_value=True)` inserts a comment in the default section, without any trailing `= None`. In order to guarantee a correct ordering of the output, a `collections.OrderedDict` is required (instead of a `dict` as in my example).

Comment: This option will only work in the case you are creating a new file. If you are editing a previous file with comments out of a section, they will all wipe :/

Answer (score 9):

Update for 3.7

I've been dealing with configparser lately and came across this post. Figured I'd update it with information relevant to 3.7.

Example 1:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.set('SECTION', '; This is a comment.', None)
```

Example 2:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config['SECTION'] = {'; This is a comment':None, 'Option':'Value')
```

Example 3: If you want to keep your letter case unchanged (default is to convert all option:value pairs to lowercase)

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.optionxform = str
config.set('SECTION', '; This Comment Will Keep Its Original Case', None)
```

Where "SECTION" is the case-sensitive section name you want the comment added to. Using "None" (no quotes) instead of an empty string ('') will allow you to set the comment without leaving a trailing "=".

Answer (score 5):

You can create variable that starts by # or ; character:

```
conf.set('default_settings', '; comment here', '')
conf.set('default_settings', 'test', 1)
```

created conf file is

```
    [default_settings]
    ; comment here = 
    test = 1
```

ConfigParser.read function won't parse first value

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
print config.items('default_settings')
```

gives

```
[('test','1')]
```

Comment: Pretty ugly with the trailing `=`.

Comment: Probably this is the best and only way with ConfigParser. Thanks

Comment: You can get rid of the trailing `=`. When you want to write a comment you just omit the third argument when calling the `set` method. Otherwise you are assigning it an empty string which results in the unwanted trailing `=`.

Comment: If the set method doesn't receive a third parameter, then it will by default be `None`. so for example if we have `conf.set('DEFAULT', '; comment')`, we would get `; comment = None`

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [ConfigUpdater](https://pypi.org/project/configupdater/). It has many more convenience options to update configuration files in a minimal invasive way.

You would basically do:

```
from configupdater import ConfigUpdater

updater = ConfigUpdater()
updater.add_section('DEFAULT')
updater.set('DEFAULT', 'test', 1)
updater['DEFAULT']['test'].add_before.comment('test comment', comment_prefix=';')
with open('./config.ini', 'w') as f:
    updater.write(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Freaky solution for the above :)
**Note** *there is a* **side-effect**, *see if that suites you*

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(comment_prefixes='///')
config.set('section', '# cmt', 'comment goes here')
```

configparse will treat comments as variables, but real software would not.
This would even preserve the comments on writes done after read of the same ini file, which is a real game changer (disappearing comments are just horrible) :) and you don't need to do `allow_no_value=True` to allow empty value, just minor visual candy :)

so the ini file would look like:

```
[section]
# cmt = comment goes here
```

which pretty much gets the job done :)
please make sure to initialize `comment_prefixes` with a string that would never appear in your ini file just in case

This worked for me in 3.9.

**Side effect** *on writing the already existing comments*. They would not disappear which was normal default, but will be converted to a similar form `# first = <remaining>`, where `first` - first word of comment, `remaining` - remaining of the comment, which would change how file looks, so be carefull...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep your application as "stock" as possible (not using external library), you may want to subclass the ConfigParser to allow reading/updating/writing with comments preserved.

For example like I did in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jip-Hop/d82781da424724b4018bdfc5a2f1318b). It has one limitation. It does not support indented section headers, comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.

```
class CommentConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
"""Comment preserving ConfigParser.

Limitation: No support for indenting section headers,
comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Backup _comment_prefixes
    self._comment_prefixes_backup = self._comment_prefixes
    # Unset _comment_prefixes so comments won't be skipped
    self._comment_prefixes = ()
    # Template to store comments as key value pair
    self._comment_template = "#{0} = {1}"
    # Regex to match the comment id prefix
    self._comment_regex = re.compile(r"^#\d+\s*=\s*")
    # List to store comments above the first section
    self._top_comments = []

def _read(self, fp, fpname):
    lines = fp.readlines()
    above_first_section = True
    # Preprocess config file to preserve comments
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("["):
            above_first_section = False
        elif line.startswith(self._comment_prefixes_backup):
            if above_first_section:
                # Remove this line for now
                lines[i] = ""
                self._top_comments.append(line)
            else:
                # Store comment as value with unique key based on line number
                lines[i] = self._comment_template.format(i, line)

    # Feed the preprocessed file to the original _read method
    return super()._read(io.StringIO("".join(lines)), fpname)

def write(self, fp, space_around_delimiters=True):
    # Write the config to an in-memory file
    with io.StringIO() as sfile:
        super().write(sfile, space_around_delimiters)
        # Start from the beginning of sfile
        sfile.seek(0)
        lines = sfile.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Remove the comment id prefix
        lines[i] = self._comment_regex.sub("", line, 1)

    fp.write("".join(self._top_comments + lines))
```

You'd use it like this to write a config file with comments:

```
parser = CommentConfigParser()
parser.read_string("""
[DEFAULT]
; test comment
test = 1
""")

with open('./config.ini', 'w') as f:
    parser.write(f)
```