# Keeping comments after reading, changing and writing config file in python

Tags: python, configuration-files

I'm very new in Python and I need to modify a configuration file. I'm able to do so using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) but the problem is that I need to keep the comments in the config file and it seems that it is not possible with it. I found [Update INI file without removing comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476554/update-ini-file-without-removing-comments), but the problem is not completely solved.

The apparent solution is to use `ConfigObj` but the comments say that it's obsolete so I don't want to use this approach.

Comment: Maybe a crude approach would be writing some regular expression to modify values.

Comment: @AndrejKesely could you be more specific?

Comment: If you need to change simple variable, you could write simple regex for it. It will change only that value and keeps all the comments intact.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. The thing is that I need to modify a lot of variables, so I don't find this approach useful in my case. Also, you may be wondering why I need the comments, well they're kind of essentials for what I want. Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-process your config file before parsing with ConfigParser, and post-process the output written by the ConfigParser, then you can change an INI file without removing comments.

I suggest to transform each comment into an option (key/value pair) during pre-processing. Then ConfigParser will then not throw the comments out. During post processing you'd then 'unpack' the comment and restore it.

To simplify the process you may want to subclass the ConfigParser and override the _read and write methods.

I've done this and [posted the CommentConfigParser class in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jip-Hop/d82781da424724b4018bdfc5a2f1318b). It has one limitation. It does not support indented section headers, comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.

```
class CommentConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
"""Comment preserving ConfigParser.

Limitation: No support for indenting section headers,
comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Backup _comment_prefixes
    self._comment_prefixes_backup = self._comment_prefixes
    # Unset _comment_prefixes so comments won't be skipped
    self._comment_prefixes = ()
    # Template to store comments as key value pair
    self._comment_template = "#{0} = {1}"
    # Regex to match the comment id prefix
    self._comment_regex = re.compile(r"^#\d+\s*=\s*")
    # List to store comments above the first section
    self._top_comments = []

def _read(self, fp, fpname):
    lines = fp.readlines()
    above_first_section = True
    # Preprocess config file to preserve comments
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("["):
            above_first_section = False
        elif line.startswith(self._comment_prefixes_backup):
            if above_first_section:
                # Remove this line for now
                lines[i] = ""
                self._top_comments.append(line)
            else:
                # Store comment as value with unique key based on line number
                lines[i] = self._comment_template.format(i, line)

    # Feed the preprocessed file to the original _read method
    return super()._read(io.StringIO("".join(lines)), fpname)

def write(self, fp, space_around_delimiters=True):
    # Write the config to an in-memory file
    with io.StringIO() as sfile:
        super().write(sfile, space_around_delimiters)
        # Start from the beginning of sfile
        sfile.seek(0)
        lines = sfile.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Remove the comment id prefix
        lines[i] = self._comment_regex.sub("", line, 1)

    fp.write("".join(self._top_comments + lines))
```