# Is it possible to keep the format of INI file after change it with ConfigParser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, ini, configparser

Is it possible that `ConfigParser` keeps the format of `INI` config file? I have config files which have comments and specific `section`/`option` names and if a read and change the content of file the `ConfigParser` re-format it (I can solve the `section`/`option` names).

I am familiar with the way of working of `ConfigParser` (Read key/value pairs to a `dict` and dumping it to the file after change). But I am interested if there is solution to keep the original format and comments in the `INI` file.

**Example:**

**`test.ini`**

```ini
# Comment line
; Other Comment line
[My-Section]
Test-option = Test-Variable
```

**`test.py`**

```py
import configparser as cp

parser: cp.ConfigParser = cp.ConfigParser()
parser.read("test.ini")

parser.set("My-Section", "New-Test_option", "TEST")

with open("test.ini", "w") as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)
```

**`test.ini` after run script**

```ini
[My-Section]
test-option = Test-Variable
new-test_option = TEST
```

As you can see above the comment lines (both types of comments) have been removed. Furthermore, the `option` names have been re-formatted.

If I add the following line to source code then I can keep the format of the `options` but the comments are still removed:

```
parser.optionxform = lambda option: option
```

So the `test.ini` file after run the script with above line:

```ini
[My-Section]
Test-option = Test-Variable
New-Test_option = TEST
```

**So my question(s):**

- Is it possible to keep the comments in the `INI` file after change it?
- Is it possible to keep the formatting of file eg.: spaces, tabs, new lines etc...?

**Note:**

- I have already checked the `RawConfigParser` module but as I saw that also doesn't support the format keeping.

Comment: The docs state, `Note Comments in the original configuration file are not preserved when writing the configuration back.`.

Comment: If someone hasn't already done it, you will probably have to subclass ConfigParser and modify it to keep track of comments and  where they belong.

Comment: Does [Writing comments to files with ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620637/writing-comments-to-files-with-configparser) answer your question? [Update INI file without removing comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476554/update-ini-file-without-removing-comments).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The linked SO question/answers are not really solutions for me because I have comments outside of `sections`, furthermore I want to keep the existing comments in the `INI` file and do not add new ones. Probably you are right, I have to write and own (extend the `ConfigParser` module) parser... I hoped somebody has already faced with this issue and made (found) something solution for it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [configobj](https://github.com/DiffSK/configobj) Python module which does what I want.

**As their documentation says:**

> All comments in the file are preserved
>
> The order of keys/sections is preserved

I have changed the build-in `configparser` to `configobj` and it works as charm.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Comments in the original configuration file are not preserved when writing the configuration back.

**IF** comments are **always** before section names you could preprocess and post process the file to capture comments and restore them after the changes were made. This is a bit of a hack but maybe easier to implement than extending configparser.ConfigParser.

Does not account for in-line comments although the same method could be employed to find, associate, and restore inline comments.

Use a regular expression to find comments then associate them with sections.

```
import configparser as cp
import re

pattern = r'([#;][^[]*)(\[[^]]*\])'
rex = re.compile(pattern)
# {section_name:comment}
comments = {}
with open('test.ini') as f:
    text = f.read()
for comment,section in rex.findall(text):
    comments[section] = comment
```

Make the changes with ConfigParser.

```
parser: cp.ConfigParser = cp.ConfigParser()
parser.read("test.ini")

parser.set("My-Section", "New-Test_option", "TEST")

with open("test.ini", "w") as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)
```

Restore the comments.

```
with open('test.ini') as f:
    text = f.read()
for section,comment in comments.items():
    text = text.replace(section,comment+section)
with open('test.ini','w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

---

test.ini

```
# comment line
; other comment line
[My-Section]
test-option = Test-Variable

; another pesky comment

[foo-section]
this-option = x
```

The `comments` dict looks like:

```
{'[My-Section]': '# comment line\n; other comment line\n',
 '[foo-section]': '; another pesky comment\n\n'}
```

test.ini after changes

```
# comment line
; other comment line
[My-Section]
test-option = Test-Variable
new-test_option = TEST

; another pesky comment

[foo-section]
this-option = x
```

---

Finally here is a subclass of ConfigParser with the _read and _write_section methods overridden to find/associate/restore comments **IF** they *appear* just before sections.

```
import configparser as cp
from configparser import *
import re
class ConfigParserExt(cp.ConfigParser):
    def _read(self, fp, fpname):
        """Parse a sectioned configuration file.
        Each section in a configuration file contains a header, indicated by
        a name in square brackets (`[]`), plus key/value options, indicated by
        `name` and `value` delimited with a specific substring (`=` or `:` by
        default).
        Values can span multiple lines, as long as they are indented deeper
        than the first line of the value. Depending on the parser's mode, blank
        lines may be treated as parts of multiline values or ignored.
        Configuration files may include comments, prefixed by specific
        characters (`#` and `;` by default). Comments may appear on their own
        in an otherwise empty line or may be entered in lines holding values or
        section names. Please note that comments get stripped off when reading configuration files;
        unless they are positioned just before sections
        """

        # find comments and associate with section
        try:
            text = fp.read()
            fp.seek(0)
        except AttributeError as e:
            text = ''.join(line for line in fp)
        rex = re.compile(r'([#;][^[]*)(\[[^]]*\])')
        self.preserved_comments = {}
        for comment,section in rex.findall(text):
            self.preserved_comments[section] = comment
        
        super()._read(fp,fpname)

    def _write_section(self, fp, section_name, section_items, delimiter):
        """Write a single section to the specified `fp`."""
        # restore comment to section
        if f'[{section_name}]' in self.preserved_comments:
            fp.write(self.preserved_comments[f'[{section_name}]'])
        super()._write_section( fp, section_name, section_items, delimiter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time to present it! I have found the "configobj" module which does what I want without any hacking. You can find the documentation link my answer for further details, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd not want to use an external library, then you could pre-process your config file before parsing with ConfigParser, and post-process the output written by the ConfigParser, then you can change an INI file without removing comments.

I suggest to transform each comment into an option (key/value pair) during pre-processing. Then ConfigParser will then not throw the comments out. During post processing you'd then 'unpack' the comment and restore it.

To simplify the process you may want to subclass the ConfigParser and override the _read and write methods.

I've done this and [posted the CommentConfigParser class in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jip-Hop/d82781da424724b4018bdfc5a2f1318b). It has one limitation. It does not support indented section headers, comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.

```
class CommentConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
"""Comment preserving ConfigParser.

Limitation: No support for indenting section headers,
comments and keys. They should have no leading whitespace.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Backup _comment_prefixes
    self._comment_prefixes_backup = self._comment_prefixes
    # Unset _comment_prefixes so comments won't be skipped
    self._comment_prefixes = ()
    # Template to store comments as key value pair
    self._comment_template = "#{0} = {1}"
    # Regex to match the comment id prefix
    self._comment_regex = re.compile(r"^#\d+\s*=\s*")
    # List to store comments above the first section
    self._top_comments = []

def _read(self, fp, fpname):
    lines = fp.readlines()
    above_first_section = True
    # Preprocess config file to preserve comments
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("["):
            above_first_section = False
        elif line.startswith(self._comment_prefixes_backup):
            if above_first_section:
                # Remove this line for now
                lines[i] = ""
                self._top_comments.append(line)
            else:
                # Store comment as value with unique key based on line number
                lines[i] = self._comment_template.format(i, line)

    # Feed the preprocessed file to the original _read method
    return super()._read(io.StringIO("".join(lines)), fpname)

def write(self, fp, space_around_delimiters=True):
    # Write the config to an in-memory file
    with io.StringIO() as sfile:
        super().write(sfile, space_around_delimiters)
        # Start from the beginning of sfile
        sfile.seek(0)
        lines = sfile.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Remove the comment id prefix
        lines[i] = self._comment_regex.sub("", line, 1)

    fp.write("".join(self._top_comments + lines))
```